# C++: Can I use smart pointers with templates?

Tags: c++, templates, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

I have an abstract base class `distributions` with two derived classes, `continuous_distribution` and `discrete_distribution`. I have a function `make_distribution` with an `unordered_map` that returns a smart pointer to a (continuous) distribution,

```
std::shared_ptr<continuous_distribution> make_distribution(std::tuple<std::string, float, float> DIST) 
{
    std::string name = std::get<0>(DIST);
    float a = std::get<1>(DIST);
    float b = std::get<2>(DIST);
    
    std::unordered_map<std::string,std::shared_ptr<continuous_distribution>> MAP = {
        std::make_pair("cauchy", std::make_shared<cauchy>(a, b)),
        std::make_pair("exponential", std::make_shared<exponential>(a)),
        {...}
    };

    return MAP[name];
}
```

Because of the two derived classes, I was wondering if there is a way to make use of a template to write a single function that returns a pointer to the respective type of distribution. I tried using the following,

```
template <class type>
std::shared_ptr<type> make_distribution(std::tuple<std::string, float, float> DIST) 
{
    std::string name = std::get<0>(DIST);
    float a = std::get<1>(DIST);
    float b = std::get<2>(DIST);

    std::unordered_map<std::string,std::shared_ptr<type>> MAP = {
        std::make_pair("cauchy", std::make_shared<cauchy>(a, b)),
        std::make_pair("exponential", std::make_shared<exponential>(a)),
        {...}
    };

    return MAP[name];
}
```

However, when calling this function,

```
int main()
{
    std::tuple<std::string, float, float> TARGET{"cauchy", 1, 1};
    std::shared_ptr<continuous_distribution> target = make_distribution(TARGET);
}
```

I get an error that I don't quite understand,

```
no instance of function template "make_distribution" matches the argument list -- argument types are: (std::tuple<std::string, float, float>)
```

Comment: If you have an abstract class, that implies polymorphism, which means you should be using a pointer to that base abstract class, like `std::shared_ptr<distribution>`

Comment: What is definition of `TARGET`? PS: Minimal reproducible example would be good too.

Comment: please post a [mcve]. The error very much comes from what `TARGET` is, without knowing what it is we cannot help

Comment: btw already the complete error message should contain that information

Comment: Are `cauchy`/`exponential` inherits from both `continuous_distribution` and `discrete_distribution`?

Comment: I thought about using a pointer to the base class, but the derived classes also contain non-virtual member functions which I need to make use of. Maybe a better way would be to attempt to make those functions virtual with templates because they differ in return type.

Comment: @Daphne like NathanOliver said, you really should have `make_distribution()` return  `shared_ptr<distribution>` to fully leverage your polymorphism, but you can use [`static_pointer_cast` or `dynamic_pointer_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/pointer_cast) when you absolutely need to access members of a derived class that don't exist in the base class.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I didn't know about pointer casting, but that's exactly what I needed to get polymorphism to work. I can't thank you enough!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Template parameters can only be deduced from the calling function parameters, they are NOT deduced from the return type. And none of the parameters in your function depend on template parameters, hence no match.

In your case you have to specify template parameter EXPLICITLY and it should work:

```
std::shared_ptr<continuous_distribution> target = make_distribution<continuous_distribution>(TARGET);
```